# Wrap link text within button to take up less than 100% of the width of the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to make buttons where 70% of the width is taken up by link text and the other 30% is taken up by a background image.

Here is an example of what I mean and what the problem is:

[image]

As you can see in the photo, the text continues over the background image. I want the last word to appear below the other two instead so that it looks better. Is there a way to do this?

```
<a href="chickentikka.html" class="btn btn-success recipes" id="chickentikka_button" style="background-image: url('images/ChickenTikka.jpeg');">
<span class="linktext">
Chicken Tikka Masala
</span>
</a>
```

EDIT2:
CSS

```
contentsdiv{
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.btn-success{
  width: 100%;
}
#contentsdiv li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21%;
}

.recipes{
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#ffffff;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:0.6vw;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 30% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 2px;

}
.linktext{
  max-width: 70%;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

As far as I can see these are all the rules that have any effect on the buttons.

Comment: what does your HTML look like

Comment: @jeff fabiny I've edited the OP to show the html.

Comment: what does your CSS look like

Comment: [**LINKS ARE NOT BUTTONS**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

Comment: @Paulie_D true. I just called it a button cos I want it to be styled like one.

Answer (score 2):

The `a` tag is the containing element of your text, so the text will naturally span the entire width of the container.  You will need to put the text in its own container and control the width of that container.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <p>Chicken</p>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  max-width:70%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this and for some reason it just doesn't do anything at all. Perhaps there's another css rule that's getting in the way somewhere.

Comment: @DavidNugent Sry, you're right. The `max-width` property is used with a a `block level element`, of which `span` is not, but `p` is.

Comment: Or just set the `span` to `inline-block`...would be simpler

Comment: I've tried using `p` instead of `span` and setting `inline-block` on both and there are no results at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://codepen.io/loruit/pen/QNaVre

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white
}
.main{
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
}
.text{
  max-width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image{
  background: url(http://reemx.xtgem.com/jpg/jp0.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```